# How to filter array of objects with nested arrays based on other arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, filtering

I have an array of objects. I want to filter to include only objects where all of the elements in the test arrays are present in the original array.

Sample code.

```
const cards = [
    {
        id: "1",
        name: "J",
        tag: ["red", "yellow", "blue", "white"],
        size: ["small", "medium"],
    },
    {
        id: "2",
        name: "S",
        tag: ["red", "green", "black"],
        size: ["small", "medium"],
    },
    {
        id: "3",
        name: "K",
        tag: ["green", "purple", "brown", "white"],
        size: ["large"],
    }
```

Test arrays

```
const sizeArray = ["medium", "small"];
const tagArray = ["red", "black"];
```

I want the filtered array to only include the second object.

I've tried with filter, includes and no luck looking over many other answers to similar questions.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: `.filter` with two calls to `.every` as in `sizeArray.every(s => obj.size.includes(s)) && (the same for tagArray)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing this might be what you need:

```js
const cards = [
    {
        id: "1",
        name: "J",
        tag: ["red", "yellow", "blue", "white"],
        size: ["small", "medium"],
    },
    {
        id: "2",
        name: "S",
        tag: ["red", "green", "black"],
        size: ["small", "medium"],
    },
    {
        id: "3",
        name: "K",
        tag: ["green", "purple", "brown", "white"],
        size: ["large"],
    }
];

const sizeArray = ["medium", "small"];
const tagArray = ["red", "black"];
// filtering the cards array
const filltered = cards.filter(ch => {
    // according have every size in sizeArray and
    // every tag in tagsArray
    return sizeArray.every(size => ch.size.includes(size))
        && tagArray.every(tag => ch.tag.includes(tag));
});

console.log(filltered);
```